# Django: How do I change the HTML output of a Django form element?

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a date of birth selection of **three** select drop down boxes. My Django template looks like this:

```
<label>Date of birth</label>
{{ reg_form.date_of_birth }}
```

But I need to change the HTML of each element. For example I need to wrap each `select` element in a `div` individually.

I had a look for `date_of_birth` in the code and I found this:

`date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1920, 2010)))`

Is there a template somewhere that I can modify the HTML output of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not so cleanly, I solved this problem using jQuery as follows.

I targeted each of the three select elements that were generated by Django in the HTML, and then used the `.wrap()` function to wrap them in `div` elements.