# Changing the form HTML in Django authentication form

Tags: django

I like the idea of using the builtin form authentication in Django, but what is the most cleanest way of changing the form HTML elements without destroying everything? I am trying to use as many standard functions as possible combined with my own HTML template/style.

Comment: What do you mean by 'destroying everything' ? Also, can you provide some detail of what you've already tried.

Comment: @Joe, what i mean is eg. to modify `form.username.label_tag` to my own custom needs, if thats possible or creating a entirely new widget for the purpose?

Comment: If i can change attributes in the form elements even that would solve my problem.

Comment: Have you taken a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ I assume you want to change what is rendered on the frontend (like a label eg. changing username to UserName) ? Also, there is another solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031501/django-how-do-i-change-the-html-output-of-a-django-form-element

Comment: I want to eg. add a class to a label and input, by using the default `django.contrib.auth.views`. Unless this is impossible and i have to create my own custom authentication?

Comment: Are you new to Django?

Comment: I am pretty new in this, especially the forms extended from django itself. Im not quite certain how to override these elements.

Comment: You should use the link I provided to the documentation. Working through it will help you understand how forms work, because either I'm not understanding your question clearly or your question doesn't make sense or both.

Comment: I understand the documentation for normal custom forms. But i want to inject a `class` attribute in my form elements while using `django.contrib.auth.views`. Is this possible or do i need to create a custom authentication from scrap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643884/how-do-i-extend-the-django-login-form solved my problem.

Comment: Why don't you just either extend the template or completely overwrite the template?

Comment: @petkostas, ended up overriding the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default template like this

> If you’d prefer not to call the template registration/login.html, you
>   can pass the template_name parameter via the extra arguments to the
>   view in your URLconf. For example, this URLconf line would use
>   myapp/login.html instead:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$',
 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
 {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),
```

source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login